# ¿Se puede pasar codigo de MatLab a C++?

Tags: c++, matlab

Hola quería consultar si puedo pasar un codigo de MatLab a C++.

Adjunto codigo de MatLab:

```
N=10
i_number= 78999999;
i_sqrt= i_number;

for i=1:N
    i_sqrt= floor(((i_number/i_sqrt)+i_sqrt)/2);
end
```

Comment: QUE? si estoy preguntando si se puede hacer @BetaM

Comment: Ver la [documentación](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-c-1.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estoy muy puesto en C++ pero creo que la sintaxis es similar a Java (Si estoy puesto).

Para empezar definimos `#include <iostream>` que es un componente de la biblioteca estándar **(STL)** del lenguaje de programación y que es utilizado para operaciones de entrada/salida. De ahí el acrónimo de su nombre **Input/Output Stream**.

A continuación, como tu código de MatLab incluye la función `floor` que permite redondear un valor, debemos usar la función equivalente en C++ que en este caso equivale a la función `round`. Esta función está incluida en la librería **cmath** por lo que es necesaría importala de la forma `#include <nombre_librería>`.

Seguidamente definimos `using namespace std;` que permite usar todas las variables en el espacio de nombres "estándar". Respecto al uso de esta sentencia no estoy muy seguro sobre cuál es más eficiente o en qué casos emplearla dado que, existen otras como `std::cout` y `std::cin`.

Por último, es necesario definir un **método main (principal)** el cuál incluirá el resto de código. **Todo método, clase, bucle o condicional debe estar delimitado por una** `{` **de apertura y una** `}` **de cierre**. Se define una variable de la forma:

```
tipo_dato  nombre_variable = dato;
```

**Por ejemplo:**

```
int a = 4;
string nombre = "Learning Developer";
bool verificacion = true;
```

Una vez definido el **método main** y las variables necesarias procedemos a definir el **bucle for** necesario. Dado que, se trata de un **bucle** debe estar delimitado por `{}`. El **ciclo** incluye tres "partes" en las que, se define la variable que interviene únicamente en el bucle, `i` en nuestro caso, inicializada a 1, separado por `;` establecemos la condición a cumplir y por último el incremento de `i` que se expresa como `i++`

Por tanto, el código final quedaría:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 10;
    int i_number = 78999999;
    int i_sqrt = i_number;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        i_sqrt = round(((i_number/i_sqrt) + i_sqrt) / 2);
    }
   return i_sqrt;
}
```

Comment: Ycomo hago para que se muestre el valor en pantalla del i_sqrt? Learning Developer

Comment: Retorna la variable en cuestión haciendo uso de la sentencia `return`

Answer (score -3):

Existen herramientas que seguramente hagan el trabajo por ti. Échale un ojo a este foro

https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/48620-generating-c-c-code-from-m-function-include-mex-file

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.